# POST or PUT requests are acting like GET requests

Tags: powershell, rest, http, https

This is a simple problem that makes no sense.

I'm attempting to upload a file to my own personal website, but for whatever reason, I cannot get it to upload. Instead, my POST and PUT requests are acting like GET requests instead.

Here's the code I'm using. Very short, very simple.

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://www.mywebsite.com/destination/" -Method Post -ContentType 'image/jpg' -InFile C:\...download.jpg`

Whenever I run this code, I ALWAYS get an HTML file as a response. If I try and use a file as a destination, I receive the contents of the file.

I'm really confused. I don't know what is going on, or how to fix it.

Comment: What platform is your site hosted on? (E.g. Wordpress, an off-the-shelf cms, or a home-brewed website?). Are you sure the platform even supports POST and PUT methods?

Comment: In addition to what ^ said, it could be a login page because you didn't pass authentication information.

Comment: Try `postman` app and figure out if the APIs are working as expected.

Comment: @mclayton It is a home-brewed website. It's hosted on Hostinger.

Comment: @SagePourpre It isn't a login page, because it's actually giving me the default html page for the folder that I'm trying to use as the destination

Comment: @Sid I will try that out, but I don't know if that will change anything. I think Postman will get the same result.

Comment: Have you managed to upload files this way in the past?
It seems odd that you're posting to a directory - rather than a specific page. And that you're able to POST files to upload with no authentication at all.

Comment: @jaykeblakk - is it a "home-brewed" site as in you developed it yourself using ASP.NET / MVC (or other programming language) or you designed the graphics and layout yourself using a "website builder" wizard? Can you get the server logs for your specific request? And if it was based on a Hostinger-specific CMS you might need to raise a support request with them to check they support POST / PUT...

Comment: @jaykeblakk - and also, does the HTML page you get in response tell you anything? E.g. an error message, pointer to a Hostinger FAQ, or other useful information?

Comment: Did you also write up the APIs yourself? Because the functionalities of the `methods` are defined by how you wrote the API functions. That is why I suggested `Postman` as it would allow you to verify their functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is usually related to browser security features. 
because the website is hosted on a non-https host.
try adding https before the URL